# Python import error no circular dependencies

Tags: python

I've only started my project and already got a problem.
File parser.py contains following code and nothing more:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
```

for file parser_tests.py I tried following combinations:
1)

```
import unittest


class ParserTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def one(self):
        from parser import A
        x = A()
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

2)

```
import unittest
from parser import A


class ParserTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def one(self):
        x = A()
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

3)

```
import unittest
import parser


class ParserTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def one(self):
        x = parser.A()
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

But all of them lead to AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'A' or ImportError: cannot import name 'A'

How to fix this?

Comment: Where is your file located, and where are you running it from?  There is a builtin Python module called `parser`, which is likely what you're importing instead of your own file.

Answer (score 1):

`parser` is a python standard library module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/parser.html

You'll have to rename your module to something else